# Play Framework: Bind from request returns 'null'

Tags: java, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.2

I've created an edit view for my model 'Elk', but when I click submit, I only get 'null'.

In 'editElk' I prefill the form with data from the database. This data is rendering correctly in the view. The error occurs when I click 'submit'. I've commented the line giving me 'No value'. I've followed the computer-database-jpa sample, but I just cant understand why my form is returning 'no value'.

This is my controller:

```
import play.data.*;
import static play.data.Form.*;

@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public static Result editElk(Long id) {
    Form<Elk> editElkForm = form(Elk.class).fill(Elk.findById(id));
    return ok(views.html.tableio.editelk.render("Edit Elg", editElkForm));
}

@Transactional
public static Result submitEditedElk() {
    Form<Elk> submittedForm = form(Elk.class).bindFromRequest();
    submittedForm.get().toTableData(); // Gives: IllegalStateException: No value] 
    if (submittedForm.hasErrors()) {
        return ok(views.html.tableio.editelk.render("Edit Elg - Error",
                submittedForm));
    } else {
        submittedForm.get().update(submittedForm.get().getId());
        return TODO;

    }
}
```

And this is my editElk view:

```
@(title: String, elkForm: Form[Elk])
@import helper._
@main(title){

<h5>Edit</h5>

@form(action = routes.TableIO.submitEditedElk()) { 
@inputText(elkForm("area"))
@inputText(elkForm("sex"))
@inputDate(elkForm("date"))
@inputText(elkForm("weigth"))
@inputText(elkForm("veal"))
@inputText(elkForm("antlers"))
@inputText(elkForm("age"))
@inputText(elkForm("twin"))
@inputText(elkForm("sumTick"))
@inputText(elkForm("sumLice"))

<button type="submit">Save</button>
  }

}
```

And finally my routes file:

```
GET     /editelk/:elkid             controllers.TableIO.editElk()
POST    /submitEditedElk            controllers.TableIO.submitEditedElk()
```

**Edit**
As requested, added the Elk class.

```
@Entity
public class Elk {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long            id;

@Required
private Date            date;

@Required
private int             weight;

@Required
private double          age;

@Required
private int             antlers;

@Required
private int             veal;

@Required
private int             twin;

@Required
@ManyToOne
private Tick            sumTick;

@Required
@ManyToOne
private DeerLice        sumLice;

@Required
@ManyToOne
private Sex             sex;

@Required
@ManyToOne
private Area            area;

@Required
@ManyToOne
private HuntingField    huntingfield;

public static Elk findById(Long id) {
    return JPA.em().find(Elk.class, id);
}

@Transactional
public void save() {
    this.sumTick = Tick.findById(sumTick.id);
    this.sumLice = DeerLice.findById(sumLice.id);
    this.sex = Sex.findById(sex.id);
    JPA.em().persist(this);
}
}
```

I have omitted the getters and setters.

Comment: Post your `Elk` model class. The `IllegalStateException` is most likely being thrown because your form object has validation errors, so it would be helpful to see what validation rules you have defined in your model.

Comment: Hi thanks for your comment. I've added the `Elk` model. I didn't add it because I thought the error I was getting wasn't related to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your first issue might be the typo you have in your `weight` input field:

```
@inputText(elkForm("weigth")) // Should be @inputText(elkForm("weight"))
```

With this typo, when you submit a form there won't be a `weight` key in the body of your HTTP POST request. Consequently, when you bind the POST data to a form object in the following statement:

```
Form<Elk> submittedForm = form(Elk.class).bindFromRequest();
```

The `weight` attribute of the wrapped `Elk` will be zero. Your form will therefore be considered invalid because `weight` is a required value.

> To clarify, the `IllegalStateException` you're getting isn't because
>   there's a bug in your view or model code. It is because you're trying
>   to unwrap a form object that contains validation errors. As the
>   documentation and samples illustrate, you should only call the
>   `get()` method on a form after you've called `.hasErrors()` and it
>   has returned `false`.

After correcting this typo, I'd probably have a look at what's getting sent for your non-primitive fields (`sumTick`, `sumLice`, `sex`, `area`, `huntingField`). I'm going to go ahead and assume that the associated types in your model class are enums. If this is the case, you should check that the values being submitted are names of corresponding enum values (in which case the binding will produce a valid form).

#### Update

Your `date` field skipped my attention. If you're submitting dates in a `yyyy-MM-dd` format, add the following annotation to the `date` attribute on your model class.

```
@Required
@Formats.DateTime(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
private Date date;
```

This is the approach taken in the [sample projects](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/samples/java/computer-database/app/models/Computer.java). With this annotation Play will populate the Date field in your form object with the date String from the POST submission.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've fixed the typo. Although I probally should use Enums, I've used tables. Now that I understand the `llegalStateException` much better, I see that the error is what I was telling the formhelper to expect. By that I mean I was writing `sumTick` not `sumTick.id`. The only error I'm getting now is on the `date` field. I'm inputting `2013-10-13`, the same that is prefilled, but it says it is an `Invalid value` Any ideas?

Comment: Still getting `Invalid value`. I've even tried what they did in the sample. `@inputText(elkForm("date"), '_label -> "The Date")` When I look at the html source code I can confirm that the values being returned as invalid are `2013-10-13` Even tried changing the database date to `yyyy/MM/dd` but that didn't work either.

Comment: Just got over 2.5K views on this so a little update. The Date error I was getting was due to a bad import. If I remember correctly I was importing java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date